# How to get a path to the 'wwwroot' from a separate project in .NET 8?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Microsoft has changed something in .NET 8.

I have two projects:

1. MyApplication.Api (it is the main project with 'wwwroot', ASP.NET Core Web API)
2. MyApplication.Infrastructure (this is a library, here I need a path to the 'wwwroot')

**Dependencies:**

> MyApplication.Api -------> MyApplication.Infrastructure

So MyApplication.Infrastructure doesn't has access to MyApplication.Api.

In the previous version of .NET I could add to a project:

- Microsoft.NETCore.App
- using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
- inject IWebHostEnvironment and use 'WebRootPath':

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

public class FileService
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public FileService(
        IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        //_environment = environment;
    }

    public void SaveFile()
    {
        string webRootPath = _environment.WebRootPath;
    }
}
```

Now in .NET 8 it was removed.......
Is there any other solution to get 'wwwroot' path from **a project which is a library**?

Comment: _Microsoft has changed something in .NET 8_: Yes, this is very likely. The following may be of interest: [What's new in .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8/overview) and [Breaking changes in .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/8.0)

Comment: I know that but there is no information how to replace it.

Comment: maybe try with AppContext.BaseDirectory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory?view=net-8.0 (should be parent of wwwroot)

Answer (score 2):

`IWebHostEnvironment` is still present in `.net8` but is now part of another package [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref)

EDIT:

But to use it in your class `lib` you need to modify your `.csproj` and add this :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```